# How to communicate b/w web app and ASP.NET Web API with secure token communication

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

We configured Azure web app infrastructure such way that consist

1. customer web portal and WebApp API site

   **Scenario**: when a user accessing a customer web portal where all requests communicate from Web API like (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT).

   Here actually the problem is Web API portal is publicly available for now (but I don't know about for what extent Web API visible to users publicly still requires or not?).

   In our case Customer ----API call should be in internal communication only there no third-party vendors supply.

   Is there any methods secure the cus--API.
2. We tried to secure cus---API azure network restrictions in Web API network settings but that not helps us (we got stuck the complete cus--API communication is blocked)
3. As I mentioned Web API hide from the internet then we applied Azure AD authentication for Web API.

   In this case, we got results were negative
4. we have no prior knowledge from code level securing and communication token generation

   Finally, we looking for suggestions, and suggest me what are security checks to WEB APP-API COMMUNICATING WITH CUSTOMER PORTAL. WHAT ARE SECURITY CHECKS THAT NEED FIGURE OUT?

Another big problem is really WEBAPP-API put publicly if yes then what are the ways to tighten security.

Please share ideas and suggestion it would be greatly helpful to us.

Thank you